# Paypal agreement for manual pay in any time

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

Is any way to create subscription/agreement for paying in any time?

For example: user once sign agreement for x-site.xx and system   will be create  invoice for different price in any time, but user will not need sign again.

May I read about it in documentation?

*something like that implemented in Myworks Paypal gateway for whmcs*

Comment: Maybe https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/recurring-billing/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to try out Billing Agreement - Reference Transaction.

Read it here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/

You can have an agreement with the buyer and charge them anytime you want with any amount you wanted too.